# SQL Table Partition Error - Cannot Add A New Partition To Existing Partitioned Table

Tags: sql-server-2005, database-design

I have inherited a SQL Server and I have discovered a table partitioning issue.  I cannot add a new partition to an existing table partition for reasons I am unsure of.

**Environment:**

SQL Server 2005 Enterprise,
Database approximately 400GB in size,
4GB RAM,
32 BIT system only.

**Partitioned Table Details:**

*Table is partitioned across 13 filegroups on multiple disk volumes.

*Partition Function is RANGE LEFT with 12 boundary points that are datetime values.

*Boundary points are structured in a date quarterly structure (example: 2009-12-31 23:59:59, 2010-03-31 23:59:59, 2010-06-30 23:59:59).

*The datetime value is the Partition Key.

*Data is inserted daily into the table based on the current date, however only the last filegroup receives data as the last boundary point on the function is '2010-06-30 23:59:59'.

*Table has a Clustered Index that is aligned with the table, and 3 Non-Unique Non-Clustered Indexes (2 are aligned, 1 exists on a different filegroup altogether).

*Current Table volume details:

Data Space: 75GB+

Index Space:    50GB+

Row Count:  200 million+

**Issue:**

Currently the last filegroup/partition has no maximum date boundary point, so all data after the date '2010-06-30 23:59:59' has been/is still being inserted into this partition.  Luckily transactional data volumes are rather small, however over a two year period the final partition has grown to an impressive 22GB size.  I do not wish to split or remove data from this existing partition.  I do however want to add a new filegroup and alter the existing partition function so that all future data is inserted into the new filegroup.  I want to add a new future date as a boundary point so that all inserted data after that date goes to a new filegroup/partition.

**Method Used:**

Added a new filegroup/file using the ALTER DATABASE function - *SUCCESS*.

Altered the Partition Scheme so that the newly created filegroup was allocated 'NEXT USED' - *SUCCESS*.
--SCRIPT USED TO ALTER PARTITION SCHEME--

ALTER PARTITION SCHEME [partition_scheme_name]
NEXT USED (new_filegroup_name);

Altered the Partition Function to add the new boundary point - *FAIL*.

--SCRIPT USED TO ADD NEW BOUNDARY POINT TO FUNCTION--

ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION partition_function_name()
SPLIT RANGE ('2012-10-01 23:59:59)
GO

**Error:**

Adding the new boundary point to the existing partition using the SPLIT RANGE technique failed because the database transaction log filled up (restricted to 18GB).  This took me by surprise for 2 reasons - 1): I thought using SPLIT RANGE was a metadata function only (please correct me if I am wrong) and 2): my new boundary point does not exist in the table as yet as a date value so I assumed there would be no data movement.

**What I have tried so far:**

*I tested this method successfully using a test server but with a much smaller dataset.

*I then restored a complete copy of the production database onto a test system.  I added a second database log file with unlimited growth and attempted to alter the Partition Function again.  The original database transaction log filled up as expected, but the secondary database transaction log grew to 60GB!  In addition the tempdb grew to 14GB.  The new filegroup started to increase in size when the whole process aborted again due to a different error.  This time the error was:

('Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'table_name' with unique index 'Index_name').

Now there are TWO things that completely puzzle me here:

1): The index mentioned in the error from testing is a Non-Clustered, Non-Unique Index - why would I get a duplicate error?

2): More to the point, I am adding a new datetime value as a new maximum boundary point and this value does not exist in the table yet.  Why would there be data movement???

As said I have tested this method using a much smaller data set and it worked perfectly.  I don't understand why it will not work with the production dataset.  Am I missing something very obvious here?  Any advice is greatly appreciated.  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to partition the partitioned Table , and the commands what i see you have used are Correct and i think you better try in the "create Scheme Query" where you will add the new boundary and also the add the new Filegroup to the "create Function Query related to the Scheme" so that  it can work perfect , by doing so the Data that is been there in previous Filegroup will get Split .

So you better try in the source of the Queries "Create Scheme and create Function" . :)